# Discrete graphics card doesn't clock down in a laptop

Tags: linux, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Recently, I've noticed that sometimes my laptop runs very hot despite nothing happening.

Nothing was using the CPU and I found that the graphics card was the culprit (see screenshot below).

Note that the CPU is running at 100% while there is no process using it.

A restart resolves the issue temporarily.

Kernel `6.8.1-arch1-1` + AMD XT Topaz R7 M260.
The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L50-B-1X4. The distribution is Arch Linux.

My plan is to play around with `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:09:00.0/power` when it happens again. Is there a way to debug the power management?

I know about https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213561 but can't make out whether it is related. At least the behaviour appears to be similar.

[image: screenshot]